# Encryption and decryption using MySQL and Python

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, hash

I'm new with MySQL and I'm trying to code a data manager using Python and Tkinter, saving the data in a MySQL database.
For security purpose I want to encrypt the data, and I actually can do it.
The problem is: how can I decrypt the stored data so the user can read it?
Right now I'm trying to learn how to do it using AES_ENCRYP/DECRYPT but I'm having some problems.
(I'm using MD5 only for the encryption of the login credentials)
This is the code I wrote to see the data (encrypted), I just need to decrypt it:

```
def viewNumber():
for widget in window.winfo_children():
    widget.destroy()
window.geometry("760x550")
window.configure(background="#CDCDCD")
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS numbers (id VARCHAR(1000), owner VARCHAR(1000), number VARCHAR(1000));")
mydb.commit()
text = "View your list"
textO = tk.Label(window, text=text, background="#CDCDCD", fg='black', font=('Helvetica',13))
textO.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=0, pady=15)
sql = "SELECT owner, number FROM numbers WHERE id = MD5('" + username + "');"
mycursor.execute(sql)
rows = mycursor.fetchall()
tv = ttk.Treeview(window,selectmode='browse', height=15)
tv.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=18, pady=20)
tv["columns"]=("1", "2")
tv['show']='headings'
tv.column("1",width=320, anchor='c')
tv.column("2",width=320, anchor='c')
tv.heading("1",text="Owner")
tv.heading("2",text="Number")
for i in rows:
    tv.insert('', 'end', values=i)
backBut = tk.Button(text="Back to the menu", command=numbers, background="#FDB552", activebackground="#FDB552", width=25)
backBut.grid(row=16, column=0, pady=30)
text = "© 2022 Clowny. All rights reserved."
textO = tk.Label(window, text=text, background="#CDCDCD")
textO.grid(row=17, column=0, padx=5, pady=15, sticky="w")
```

Comment: First of all MD5() is a Hashing algorithm and a hash is NOT encryption. Its also a one way hash, so the only way to see if you have the original value that you hashed is to rehash a text and see if you get the same hash this time

Comment: Also MD5 is not considered a safe hashing algorithm any more

Comment: Maybe you could do a little research here https://nitratine.net/blog/post/how-to-hash-passwords-in-python/

Comment: @RiggsFolly my bad, I know md5 is hashing not encryption. In fact I'm using md5 because when you insert your credentials in the login the software hash them and check if they are equal to one of the stored credentials. I'm trying to use aes_encryption beacuse I have to store the data and "print" it in a table so the user can see it. Is this is good method? can you help me?

Comment: I dont see any encryption being done on here

Comment: Beware, if you encrypt in the code and store on the database, you cannot search the encrypted data on the db. MySQL can do it all for you, but not using the free versions of MySQL

Comment: oh...I think I won't encrypt the data then lol